# Calculating Age in Object Type FUNCTION - Oracle

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

Please excuse my extremely basic understanding of SQL in Oracle. 
I'm currently trying to have a Method in an Object Type, my attempt looks like this:

```html
CREATE TYPE Person_Type AS OBJECT
(PersonName VARCHAR2(40),
DateBorn DATE,
DateDied DATE,
MEMBER FUNCTION get_age RETURN NUMBER)
```

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Person_Type AS
MEMBER FUNCTION get_age RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
*Some kind of IF DateDied NOT NULL*
RETURN months_between(trunc(sysdate),DateBorn))/12
END;
```

I cannot get the above to compile. Ultimately I want to be able to call the method and get somebodies age they are today.

I'm able to retrieve the ages of the people currently inside my table via: 
select months_between(TRUNC(sysdate),DateBorn)/12
as age from person_table

But I would like this as a callable method.

From *my understanding*, this way of having a method within an object type would use the DateBorn form whichever row I've retrieved? I'm obviously very wrong but just need to know what the next step is and how incorrect I am at the moment...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your question is not clear, you need to clearly tell what you tried and what is your expected output

Comment: If `DateBorn` is NULL then result will be automatically also NULL.

Comment: Hi Ravi, I'm able to use (months_between(trunc(sysdate),to_date('01-01-1990', 'dd-mm-yyyy'))/12) to return someones age based on todays date into a decimal format, but how would I translate that into a Member Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot get the above to compile. Ultimately I want to be able to
>   call the method and get somebodies age they are today.

You need to use `MAP MEMBER` inside your object. See below:

```
CREATE TYPE Person_Type AS OBJECT
(
   PersonName VARCHAR2 (40),
   DateBorn DATE,
   DateDied DATE,
   MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_age    RETURN NUMBER
)
/    
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Person_Type
AS
   MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_age
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      /*Some kind of IF DateDied NOT NULL*/
      RETURN ABS(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, DateBorn)/12);
   END;
END;
```

Usage:

```
SQL> DECLARE
       prsn   Person_Type;
       age    NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        prsn :=
          Person_Type ('XXX',
                   TO_DATE ('01-01-1990', 'dd-mm-yyyy'),
                   TO_DATE ('01-01-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));

       age := prsn.get_age;

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (age);
  END;  
 /

27.752688172043010752688172043010752692

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi Xing, would that not return the age based on what you place into ' TO_DATE('01-01-1990', 'dd-mm-yyyy'))/12 ' of the BODY? How would I get it to take the value of DateBorn?

Comment: Thank you for answering this. I just tried to run ' SELECT p.get_age() 
from person_table p 
where p.PersonId = 10000', which has a DateBorn of 05-OCT-1975 and it returned 1942.9086. I've changed the above you showed me to 'dd-mon-yyyy', where would it be going wrong?

Comment: @lesovren. Its because of the `TRUNC SYSDATE`, change the format as updated above and you get the correct result,